# Tracking bugs locally with TortoiseHg

Tags: windows, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-extension, bug-tracker

Is there any way to track issues/bugs with TortoiseHg? There are a lot of extensions for online bug trackers (Trac, Jira etc) but is there any local solution? I have found [bExtension](https://bitbucket.org/dimo414/b/src/default/) useful but it lacks a GUI. On the other hand bugzilla seems overkill for my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, I have sticked with b. I have found it very useful.